# Filesystem which heals itself, supports removable media and incremental backups

Tags: backup, filesystems, remote

I'm looking for a filesystem that heals itself like ZFS, which allows to add and remove new (remote) devices at runtime (for example to add a partition of a disk on a new computer in the network: that disk could be used as local cache like for AndrewFS or extend the capacity/self healing abilities) and which allows to assign a media as "backup disk" (which should roughly translate to: Copy all changes to the disk until it is full and then request a new backup disk).

I need it for Linux but if it works for Windows, that would be great.

Is there something like this?

Answer (score 3):

yes, it is called .. well .. [zfs](http://github.com/behlendorf/zfs). or [btrfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs).

Comment: Can I assign a backup disk with zfs? What I'm looking for is something that allows a simple and safe way to backup 5TB of data on several disks.