# storing photos best approach?

Tags: backup, filesystems

I have many photographs on my hard disk and am worried that at some point in the future I could lose them all. What's the best approach to storing them? (specific file system, software etc)

I need these functions:

- It should automatically backup when a specified backup device is available
- Use some kind of checksum / parity to check and resolve data errors in each file
- I can create a database which will store the indexing and metadata

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: I have ubuntu 10.10 along with windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently have 33,000 photographed and catalogued on my Windows PC.  My solution is as follows:

Catalogued in Adobe Lightroom,  using sidecar files for my Raw Images and embedded keywords for the JPGs(not many of these).

Lightroom creates copy/backups of the Catalogue automatically once a week which I retain for 3 months with in my Work Directory.

For backups I use the following

Syncback Pro :  which automatically backs new and changed files (several methods of Comparison available) from up my Work Folder (Photographs and all other Documents) to my NAS drive each evening.   Plus once a week I syncronise my Work Folder (and other key data) to 1 of 3 External 1Tb Harddrives which are kept in a Firesafe in my Garage.

I also use Syncback to back up all my other drives (4) to the NAS daily excluding C which is backed up every 2 days to an other internal drive using Acronis True Image and then copied to the NAS.

There is a simple rule you can not have too many copies of your important files.

Comment: How about "windows backup" in windows 7, use that to create backup on my external drive (weekly), plus syncback pro to keep another copy in sync? I want the software to automatically backup when the drive is plugged in rather at a specific time, is that possible?

Comment: Personally I have never used the Windows Backup routines,  but it should be fine,  I would make sure you have more than 1 external drive and that you check you can restore data from those devices, especially if you you are using "packed" data rather than pure files as syncback uses.

Answer (score 1):

Store the pictures on a NTFS or ext4 based filesystem that is setup on a removable drive. Do not keep this drive mounted on any system at all times. If possible setup a wireless network and host this drive over your network when required.

Store all your data files with checksums (md5sum).

You could also consider a RAID1 or RAID5/6 kind storage if you are worried about disk failures.

This is a basic approach assuming you are not looking for a professional storage solution.

You may also want to check this other question,
[Filesystem which heals itself, supports removable media and incremental backups](https://superuser.com/q/169926/263).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation as Jane described with a large number of photos (catalogue managed by Adobe Lightroom, total size about 30GB).
I use two tier backup with [Allway Sync 'n' Go](http://allwaysync.com/) as it is freeware and can be run as a portable application.

1. Backup to 1TB external drive over USB2;
2. Sync the external drive content changes to Amazon S3 using the same utility.

This way it costs me about £3/month in Amazon fees and I can always access the files.

However, if you are concerned about the security, you may want to encrypt the files before syncing. I have not really bothered as my shots do not command £3k a piece like some others...

Regards,
Taavi